# Spark partitions - using DISTRIBUTE BY option

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-partitioning

We have a Spark environment which should process 50MM rows. These rows contains a key column. The unique number of keys are close to 2000. I would like to process all of those 2000 keys in parallel. Thus we are using a Spark sql like the following

```
hiveContext.sql("select * from BigTbl DISTRIBUTE by KEY")
```

Subsequently we have a mapPartitions that works nicely on all the partitions in parallel. However the trouble is, it creates only 200 partitions by default. Using a command like the following i am able to increase the partitions

```
hiveContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=500");
```

However during real production run i would not know what is the number of unique keys. I want this to be auto managed. Is there a way to do this please.

Thanks

Bala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use "repartition" function and then register the repartitioned as a new temp table and also further cache it for faster processing.

```
val distinctValues = hiveContext.sql("select KEY from BigTbl").distinct().count() // find count distinct values 

hiveContext.sql("select * from BigTbl DISTRIBUTE by KEY")
       .repartition(distinctValues.toInt) // repartition to number of distinct values
       .registerTempTable("NewBigTbl") // register the repartitioned table as another temp table

hiveContext.cacheTable("NewBigTbl") // cache the repartitioned table for improving query performance
```

for further queries use "NewBigTbl"

Comment: Thanks so much for a quick response. I am finishing testing another functionality. Once i am done with that, will certainly try the approach that you are suggesting and update. Thanks once again for the help

Comment: Thanks @Snchit Grover. That worked very nicely. Thank you. However i am hitting another issue due to large number of partitions. We are working with Spark 1.6.1 and i think we are hitting bug SPARK-12837. Will try and see if we can upgrade to 2.0. For now this issue is closed and thanks once again.